# What is the value of these phantom units?

Tags: shares, equity, contracts

The wording of this paragraph is not clear to me. Does the value of the Phantom Units equate to 0.25% of the FMV, or do they equate to 0.25% of 10% of full FMV?

> The number of Phantom Units granted hereby is intended to equate to
>   one-quarter of one percent (0.25%) of the Fair Market Value of the
>   Company as if the maximum number of Phantom Units that may be awarded
>   under the Plan are outstanding, inclusive of the Phantom Units granted
>   hereby, which in the aggregate represent 10% of the Fair Market Value
>   of the Company, and the remaining 90% of the Fair Market Value of the
>   Company is represented by the outstanding Class A Units held by the
>   Founder Group.

For example, assuming the company is valued at $10M, which of the following two calculations correctly interprets the value of 100 Phantom Units?

A) 0.25% of 10% of $10M = $2,500

or

B) 0.25% of 100% of $10M = $25,000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The number of Phantom Units granted hereby is intended to equate to one-quarter of one percent (0.25%) of the Fair Market Value of the Company

So at a FMV of $10M they would be worth 0.0025 * $10M

The maximum value of all Phantom Shares, including yours, can't exceed 10% of the FMV

Comment: Got it. Thanks. The verbiage after the line that you quoted had me all mixed up.